# Instrumented Test not running in Android Tests Passed 0 Passed

Tags: android, testing, junit4

I have been trying to run a test case , present in androidTest Package.
But as i execute the test, Emulator launches and I get tests passed : 0 Passed.

and getting this Error in logcat

```
E/AndroidJUnitRunner: An unhandled exception was thrown by the app.


E/InstrumentationResultPrinter: Failed to mark test No Tests as finished after process crash
```

here is my code.

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyAndroidTest {

    @Test
     fun test_simple() {
        assertEquals(2, 1+1)
    }
}
```

I have added all required dependencies.

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'

testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.6"

testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"


testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.5'
// required if you want to use Mockito for Android tests
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5'
```

When I run the same test case in **test** package, it runs successfully.
One thing is, ***I created The androidTest package by myself***. It was somehow deleted earlier..

I get this after I run the test case,

[image]
[image]

plz help.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114551/android-studio-testing-shows-test-results-0-0-how-can-i-begin-the-tests.

Comment: I was facing this issue also. This solution works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77684685/10599979

Answer (score 2):

Add `testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` in defaultConfig block inside gradle module file

Is missing in that project and it's necessary.

Comment: This is already present but I still get the same problem as OP

Answer (score 1):

For me, i need to add this dependency. I dont know why it doesnt show any error. But looks like the test runner itself still needs to be added separately.

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.5.2")
```